# hide the texfield cursor in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting one issue. I want to hide the cursor after clicking sign in button 
I tried with FocusNode but it is not working .I have searched in google but I didn't get the answer.Actually what is the way to do this ? Here is my code.

```
Widget _buildUserIdField() {
  return Observer(
  builder: (context) {
    return TextFieldWidget(
      hint: AppTranslations.of(context).text("mobile_number"),
      inputType: TextInputType.text,
      textController: _userEmailController,
      inputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      fillColor: AppColors.gray[300],
      onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_passwordFocusNode);
      },
      errorText: _store.formErrorStore.userEmail,
       );
     },
   );
}

Widget _buildPasswordField() {
return Observer(
  builder: (context) {
    return TextFieldWidget(
      hint: AppTranslations.of(context).text("enter_password"),
      isObscure: true,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
      icon: Icons.lock,
      fillColor: AppColors.gray[300],
      iconColor: Colors.black54,
      textController: _passwordController,
      focusNode: _passwordFocusNode,
      errorText: _store.formErrorStore.password,
      onFieldSubmitted: (value){
        FocusScope.of(context).dispose();
      }

    );
  },
);
}

Widget _buildSignInButton() {
return RoundedButtonWidget(
  buttonText: AppTranslations.of(context).text("login"),
  buttonColor: AppColors.blue[500],
  textColor: Colors.white,
  onPressed: () async {
    FocusScope.of(context).dispose();
    if (_userEmailController.text.isNotEmpty &&
        _passwordController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      _login();
    } else {
      AlertError.showErrorMessage(context, AppTranslations.of(context).text("fill_all_fields"));
       }
     },
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
cursorColor: Colors.transparent
cursorWidth: 0
```